# How can I call a javascript function located in my html file from my php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my `index.html` I have:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/messi.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/messi.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function failureFunction(){
      new Messi('There was an error sending your message.', {title: 'Failure'});
    };      
    function successFunction(){
      new Messi('Success sending email', {title: 'Success'});
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form class="form" id="form1" method="post" action="contactengine.php">
  ...
  </form>
</body>
```

And then in my `contactengine.php` I have:

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $Headers);

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>successFunction();</script>"; 
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
else{
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>failureFunction();</script>";
 print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
```

My echo ... won't call the `successFunction()` though.  I know the `$success` var is true because if I put an alert there it calls the alert and I know that my `successFunction()` works because I can call it from my `index.html` file with no problems. The messi library is located [here](https://github.com/marcosesperon/Messi) for reference.

How can I correctly call the `successFuntion()` from my php file?

Comment: You can't. To make this work, you can submit your form using ajax and then call the `successFunction()` inside the `success` handler of the ajax function

Comment: You've defined your functions in `index.html`, and you try to call them from another page. It doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can move your JS functions inside a javascript file and include that file in the PHP or HTML pages where you need to call those functions.

### js/customMessi.js

```
function failureFunction(){
  new Messi('There was an error sending your message.', {title: 'Failure'});
};      
function successFunction(){
  new Messi('Success sending email', {title: 'Success'});
};
```

### and in your HTML file :

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/messi.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">   </script>
 <script src="js/messi.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/customMessi.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <form class="form" id="form1" method="post" action="contactengine.php">
   ...
  </form>
</body>
```

### and in your contactengine.php file as well:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='js/customMessi.js'></script>";
...
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $Headers);

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>successFunction();</script>"; 
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
else{
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>failureFunction();</script>";
 print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
```

Comment: I tried putting the <head>... both inside the <?php ?> and outside and neither worked.  I also put my customMessi.js script inside the index.html file and was able to successfully call the successFunction()... So I know customMessi.js works.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I don't work in PHP, just answered according to my thiinking. But i think something like ths should work in PHP.     ?> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/customMessi.js"></script> <?php

Comment: echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='js/customMessi.js'></script>";

Comment: echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='js/customMessi.js'></script>";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>successFunction();</script>";

Comment: To me it looks like it is under some folder, like code/contactengine.php etc. In that case you need to add ../js/customMessi.js . Invite me to chat or send me email instead of increasing comment here. For every nested foler, Add "../" in front of "js/customMessi.js".

Comment: The contactengine.php file is located at the same level as the js folder.  So I believe the structure is correct.